# Fluxbox, how to launch some applications in a specific workspace at startup

Tags: fluxbox, workspaces, window-management

I would like to launch some applications at startup, but I want them to be in a specific workspace.

I can edit the fluxbox startup-script to launch those applications, but I don't know how to specify in which workspace it must be launched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you do not need any external tools, just read `man fluxbox-apps`, edit `.fluxbox/apps` and put there something like

```
[app] (name=xyz)
   [workspace] (n)
[end]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `gdevilspie` to match this application and set the workspace.