# Fluxbox, how to launch specific instance of application in a workspace (from cli)

Tags: shell-script, command-line, workspaces, fluxbox

This almost does what I want [Fluxbox, how to launch some applications in a specific workspace at startup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49529/fluxbox-how-to-launch-some-applications-in-a-specific-workspace-at-startup)
but not quite.

I want to be able to save the position and workspace of a specific instance of an application. Can I do that?

I preferably want to do this from a bash script. but if it is possible from `.fluxbox/apps` only , it will suffice.